# Отключение прокрутки из за определенных объектов

Tags: javascript, css, прокрутка

У меня есть блок `<div id="nowrap">` и мне нужно чтобы у `<body>` не появлялась полоса прокрутки именно из-за `<div id="nowrap">`  а из-за остальных блоков появлялась.

Comment: сделайте `nowrap` `height 100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так по себе проблема простая, нам нужно поместить элемент в `<div>` c `overflow: hidden;`.

Но тогда этот `<div>` при прокрутке страницы будет обрываться ровно по ее ширине. Если мы не хотим этого, сделаем такой хак:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
}

#nowarp {
  position: absolute;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class=main>
  <div class=container>
    <div id=nowarp>wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</div>
  </div>

  <div>QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ</div>
</div>
```